# problems running local PHP file using Chrome

Tags: php, windows, google-chrome, local

I need to use Chrome to run a local PHP file.  I believe I've done all that is required to do this (acc. to multiple web sites, inc. php.net), however, all I get is a blank web page.  The things I've done to enable this capability are:

1. Install MS Visual C++ 2010 x64 Redictributable 10.0.40219
2. Enable IIS on my Windows 7 Home Premium PC by following instructions at http://php.net/manual/en/install.windows.iis7.php, including executing at the cmd line their "Examples" 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 9, and the one enabling 64 bit operation
3. download php-5.4.31-nts-Win32-VC9-x86.zip, then follow instruction re: changing the php.ini file at http://php.net/manual/en/install.windows.manual.php (e.g., copy the php.ini-production into php.ini)
4. Put my php script into the folder C:\Users\Wade\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data\Default\User Scripts the script is simple:

`<?php $row = "1.jpg";
     echo $row;
    ?>`

1. In Chrome, entered the url `http:/localhost/<script-file-name.php>`

Please help!

Answer (score 0):

If you want to run PHP on IIS server then you can go with [Microsoft Web Platform Installer](http://www.microsoft.com/web/downloads/platform.aspx).It automatically configures IIS server with PHP for you.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not used to chrome, but i doubt this folder is made to run local php script.

Do you have some reason for choosing IIS ?

If not, and if you just want to run php file locally, you'll probably find a lot easier to use some programs such as Xampp to install & configure a little Apache web server for you.

If you choose to go this way,  you need to :

1. disable or uninstall IIS , to prevent conflicts.
2. download xampp installer for windows :  https://www.apachefriends.org/fr/index.html  (some other alternatives exists, easyphp, etc.. )
3. install like any other program, the default settings are probably good enough.
4. delete all the files in the newly created c:\xampp\htdocs\ folder.
5. launch c:\xampp\xampp-control.exe (that may not be the exact name, but it's easy to spot in the folder) , and check  that the Apache module is marked as started  ( if you installed it as a service - which i think is the default - it will launch on windows start )
6. put your php files in c:\xampp\htdocs\
7. navigate to http:/localhost/

Hope this helps.